# How to write inside a Select Field WTForms Flask?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I want the user to be able to write inside the Select Field, and save in the database the value written by the user. Is there a way to do this?

I'm using WTForms with Flask in python.

I rendered the Select Field but it doesn't allow to write inside.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve I added a TextField and with JavaScript hid it. And when the user clicks inside the SelectField the TextFiel will be unhidden.